# AWS CDK pipeline with ECS service discovery as well as Route53 Cname records

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, service-discovery

I am building a pipeline with three stacks in AWS CDK (python), a vpc stack, a database stack, and an application/ecs service and container stack.
I need to have be able to create route53 cname records that connects a record name e.g. db.domain.com to a database dns,
as well as service discovery records that connects a record name e.g. serviceA.domain.com to an ECS service dns.

I am only able to do one of these currently, either by creating a private dns namespace that autocreates a route53 hosted zone that I am unable to add cname records to, because I don't know its id, or I can create a route53 hosted zone which I am unable to create records for ECS services in, because I don't know their dns's/ips.

How do I achieve both of these objectives at the same time in the AWS CDK?

Possibly another way to put the question:
How do I add CName records to a private hosted zone that is autocreated by CloudMap when creating a private dns namespace in AWS CDK?

The following approach to getting the hosted zone fails, either during deployment if I don't add vpc_id (because it returns DUMMY as hosted zone id) or when running cdk synth if I do add vpc_id with the error:

jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot determine scope for context provider hosted-zone.

This usually happens when one or more of the provider props have unresolved tokens

```
aws_route53.PrivateHostedZone.from_lookup(
    self, 
    id="zone", 
    domain_name="domain.com", 
    private_zone=True, 
    vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id 
)
```

Comment: `or I can create a route53 hosted zone which I am unable to create records for ECS services in, because I don't know their dns's.`: do you mean you don't know their IP address? Or what do you mean by "you don't know their dns's"?

Comment: I guess a better way to phrase it would be that I don't know how to target the specific service when using the Route53 A Record creation

Comment: Does your service need inbound access from the internet? If so, did you create a load balancer in front of the ECS service? Or are all services in a public subnet woth a public IP address or something?

Comment: @LRutten Currently I am just looking at internal traffic in the stacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your comments a assume you have a container service and want private access to that container service.

To expose the service using private dns you have two options. Firstly, you can create a cloud map namespace (e.g. `example.local`) and create a cloudmap service (e.g. `my-service`) under than namespace and link it to the ECS service.  You can do that using CDK. The resulting record will be `my-service.exampme.local`.
To connect to for example a database, add a cloud map service like specified in the CDK docs:

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as servicediscovery from '../lib';

const app = new cdk.App();
const stack = new cdk.Stack(app, 'aws-servicediscovery-integ');

const namespace = new servicediscovery.PublicDnsNamespace(stack, 'Namespace', {
  name: 'foobar.com',
});

# this is where the interesting stuff happens.
const service = namespace.createService('Service', {
  name: 'foo',
  dnsRecordType: servicediscovery.DnsRecordType.CNAME,
  dnsTtl: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
});

service.registerCnameInstance('CnameInstance', {
  instanceCname: 'my-database.rds.region.amazonaws.com',
});

app.synth();
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-servicediscovery-readme.html

The second way to do it is to add a load balancer in front of your service and create a hosted zone yourself and add a DNS record pointing to that load balancer. CDK has constructs available for that.

```
    // Create a load-balanced Fargate service and make it public
    new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, "MyFargateService", {
      cluster: cluster, // Required
      cpu: 512, // Default is 256
      desiredCount: 6, // Default is 1
      taskImageOptions: { image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample") },
      memoryLimitMiB: 2048, // Default is 512
      publicLoadBalancer: false // Default is false
    });
```

[Snippet taken from an AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/ecs_example.html)
Then simultaneously create another record in this hosted zone for your DB as you normally would.

Edit: regarding your snippet to get the zone, you need to add the construct to a stack for it to work. Also make sure you're on the latest CDK version. The latest version synthesizes iteratively. The first time will resolve DUMMY but the next it somehow does resolve to the right id for me. I did use the Hostezone construct though, not the PrivateHostezone.

Comment: so it doesnt error out for you after resolving to DUMMY?

Comment: Nope for me it doesn't.  What versions do you use? E.g. what does your package.json look like?

Comment: Ah I see btw that i do use the Hostezone construct, not the privatehostedzone one. Maybe switch to the hostedzone and check if that works?

Comment: the hosted zone is autocreated by the private dns namespace

Comment: I am trying to update the cdk to the newest version

Comment: Ohhh sorry I misunderstood.  You can't add records to that hosted zone name via route53. It's managed by aws cloud map. If you want you can do two things: 1. Create a new private zone with different name and create a record that points to the load balancer and described earlier.  No need to import anything then.  2. You use aws cloud map as you're doing now and then you need to add a cloud map `service` to the ECS service (i know, confusing terminology here).

Comment: The problem is not with ECS, its with adding CName records that points to RDS instances

Comment: Same thing: add a  cloud map service to the same namespace (my-database). You can set up a cname record as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-servicediscovery-readme.html. see the section on CNAME records. Add a CNAME record to cloud map pointing to your DB.

Comment: Great thank you very much, that last update seems to have pushed me in the right direction